# How do I plot a npdensity object with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, kernel-density

How do I plot a `npdensity` object with ggplot, like one from the output of `npudens`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `geom_line` together with the built-in functionality of `predict` with `npdensity`.

```
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1000))
df.kde <- npudens(~x, data=df)
ggplot(df, aes(x)) 
  + stat_function(fun = function(new.x) predict(df.kde, newdata=data.frame(x=new.x)))
```

If you have evaluated at enough x points such that the graph looks good, you can get away with using `eval$x` and `dens`.

```
geom_line(aes(df.kde$eval$x, df.kde$dens))
```